# What is the value of $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{a^x-1}{x}$ for a > 1

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I tried the following:
$$
\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {a^{x}\left( 1-\dfrac {1}{a^{x}}\right) }{x} \\
= \lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {a^{x}}{x}•\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1-\dfrac {1}{a^{x}}\right)\\
$$
I did realize that $a^x > x$   $ \forall$   $  x\epsilon R$.
But this doesn't suffice to say that the first limit in the second expression tends to infinity since we still haven't proven $a^x$ is an infinity of higher order than $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $x\to + \infty$

$$\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\frac{a^x-1}{a^x}\frac{a^x}{x}\to (1 \cdot +\infty)\to +\infty$$

indeed

- $\frac{a^x-1}{a^x}\to 1$

and since eventually $a^x\ge x^2$

- $\frac{a^x}{x}\ge\frac{x^2}{x}= x\to \infty$

For $x\to - \infty$ let $y=-x\to +\infty$

$$\lim _{x\to -\infty } \frac {a^x-1}{x}=\lim _{y\to \infty } \frac {a^{-y}-1}{-y}=\lim _{y\to \infty } \frac {a^y-1}{ya^y}=\lim _{y\to \infty } \frac1y \frac {a^y-1}{a^y}=0$$

Comment: But the value of the limit is 0 as x approaches negative infinity

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam I supposed you are asking for the limit as $x\to +\infty$, we can of course also evaluate the limit as $x\to -\infty$

Comment: How do you prove that inequality?

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam which inequality?

Comment: $a^x ≥ x^2$ for positive x

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam It is a standard result that exponential with base >1 are eventually greater than any polynomial function. Te see it we can take log both siade and obtain $x\log a \ge 2 \log x$ that is a well known result. Are you interested in this proof also?

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam it suffices to prove that $\frac{n}{e^n}\to 0$ for example by ratio test, then for $y\to \infty \implies \frac{y}{e^y}\to 0$ and setting $y=\log x\implies \frac{\log x}{x}\to 0$ then $x$ is arbitrarly larger than $\log x$ and thus $x\log a \ge 2 \log x\implies a^x\ge x^2$ eventually.

Comment: I am interested in the proof of this result. Could you just share it here? @gimusi

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam I've just added it in the previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use *equivalents*:

if $a>1$, $a^x-1\sim_{+\infty} a^x=\mathrm e^{x\ln a}$, so
$$ \frac{a^x-1}{x}\sim_{+\infty}\frac{e^{x\ln a}}x\to +\infty\quad\text{since }\ln a>0.$$

At $-\infty$, $\;a^x-1\sim -1$, so
$$\frac{a^x-1}{x}\sim_{-\infty}-\frac1x\to 0.$$